# How do I position an image at the bottom of div?

Tags: css, html, alignment

I want an html image to be flush with the bottom of a div tag.  I can't seem to find a way to accomplish this.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="span8">
  <img src="/img/play-shot1.jpg" class="text-center shadow">
</div>
```

The problem is that the div is nested within other divs that have padding or margins.

Comment: Position an image to the bottom of a div by applying this CSS attribute to the image: `position:absolute; bottom:0`

Comment: I'm not sure that this question should have been closed. I looked at several answers on stackoverflow before finding this one with Google's help. It's the only one that provided an answer that worked for me.  His question seems pretty clear to me. Does it really matter why he wanted to do it? I think that would have just padded the question out unnecessarily.

Comment: I second, not sure how more clear you can be.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Add relative positioning to the wrapping div tag, then absolutely position the image within it like this:

CSS:

```
.div-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
}

.div-wrapper img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="div-wrapper">
    <img src="blah.png"/>
</div>
```

Now the image sits at the bottom of the div.

Comment: using this method is it possible to align it in the center? text-align: center doesn't work after this absolute positioning stuff

Comment: @relipse, in case someone wonder too : margin-left & margin-right : auto, left & right : 0.

Comment: What if I have to stack more than one image one above the other ?

Answer (score 10):

Using flexbox:

HTML:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <img src="pikachu.gif"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.wrapper {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
}
```

As requested in some comments on another answer, the image can also be horizontally centred with `justify-content: center;`

Comment: thanks! this method works even without a fixed height.

Answer (score 2):

```
< img style="vertical-align: bottom" src="blah.png" >
```

Works for me. Inside a parallax div as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
.parent :"display: inline-flex;"

.child: "align-self: self-end;"
```

it work with me.