# How to align an image to the bottom of the div?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm trying to align an image to the bottom of the out `div` element using `vertical-align`,but this `vertical-align` doesn't seem to work,the image is not moving at all.

```
 <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-1">
       <img src="../images/image.png" style="height: 20px; width: 20px;cursor:pointer"/>
     </div>
     <div class=col-md-11 >
        <div  style="overflow:auto;height:300px"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

I'm using bootstrap classes for alignments. Is there anything that can make the image `div` align to the bottom of the outer `div`?Which is taking the `height` of second `div` which is `300px;`.

Comment: please make jsfiddle link or show your css also

Comment: [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520940/html-image-bottom-alignment-inside-div-container) and here is  [anotherlink](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17934332/how-do-i-position-an-image-at-the-bottom-of-div)

Comment: Use firefox - open Firebug - check out what properties are being applied / overridden under the detailed and inherited/Computed section. Adjust in browser first and apply to code next.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2603700/how-to-align-3-divs-left-center-right-inside-another-div this may help you abit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, something like this should do the trick:

```
.parent {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

You could add those classes to the DIV and the IMG respectively.

It looks like the parent div will be 300px high anyway because of the height set on the child in the adjacent div. If you specify the height of the parent instead, then you can **absolutely** position the *child* **relative** to the size of the *parent*.

If you don't set the parent as position:relative, then the child will be position relative to something else (like the page).

Vertical-align won't work because the IMG is an inline element, and the behavior you're expecting is table-cell dependent. With inline elements, vertical alignment is relative to the line and not to the parent container, so that an image aligned with text would sit in various positions relative to a given line of text.

Be sure to check the documentation for this and other questions, which is [well-explained at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align).

Answer (score 5):

You can use flexbox for this. Appling the parent styles to the DIV. No extra styling needed for `img`

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Here's what you'll want to add if you don't have a taskrunner adding the prefixes for maximum compatibility.

```
.parent {    
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-end;
            -ms-flex-pack: end;
          justify-content: flex-end;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column; 
}
```

Currently 97% of the browsers used today support flex.

Comment: The reason I prefer this option is it allows for the parent to stay flexible and still be scaled by it's children.