# How to align image at the bottom of this div?

Tags: html, css

I have 3 images, and want to show them like this:

```
AABB
AABB
AACC
AACC
```

A,B,C are the images. Because A's height is not the sum of B and C's height, so I want to show A to align to the bottom of C.

Here is the code I'm using now:

```
<div class="logo-wrap">

    <div class="site-title" style="position: relative;  " >
        <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">
        <img src="~/Images/girl.png"  />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="site-sub-header">
        <img src="~/Images/logo.png" style="height:75%;" />
        <br/>
        <img src="~/Images/icons.png" style="height:75%; " />
    </div>                

</div>
```

Based on [How do I position an image at the bottom of div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17934332/how-do-i-position-an-image-at-the-bottom-of-div) , I set logo-wrap to

```
position: relative;
```

then set the girl.png image to

```
position: absolute;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
```

But it does not work. Anyone has suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Can you create a fiddle please.

Comment: Is this what you want to achieve? [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/gvsL12yr/)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
display:inline-block;
```

to organize the row for example : "AABB".

I don't think:

```
position:absolute;
```

is a great solution for this.